# What is expected datetime string for ar-sa culture?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, locale

I have a method

```
DateToString(DateTime datetime, string format, CultureInfo cultrueInfo)
{
    return datetime.ToString(format, cultureInfo);
}
```

Parameters:

```
datetime: {10/1/2016 12:00:00 AM}
format: "ddd, dd MMM"
cultureInfo: {ar-SA}
```

But it returns me "السبت, 30 ذو الحجة". October 1st is Saturday. Why it seems return me September 30, Saturday? Anything wrong at my side?

Comment: I guess, this is caused by calendar used by ar-SA culture. For the UmAlQuraCalendar class, each month has either 29 or 30 days.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.umalquracalendar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://islamicfinder.org/islamic-date-converter/?day=11&month=8&year=2012&dateType=Gregorian

Comment: I find this and it seems it just converts it to 30, that's correct.

Comment: BTW, you _really_ don't need that method if it _only_ calls `DateTime.ToString(string, IFormatProvider)` method. Just call `datetime.ToString(format, cultureInfo)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ar-SA` culture uses [`UmAlQuraCalendar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.umalquracalendar) a calendar.

```
new CultureInfo("ar-SA").Calendar.Dump(); // System.Globalization.UmAlQuraCalendar
```

Since you used that culture in your `ToString` method, it will generated a string representation based on *that* calendar. You *can't* expect to generate "September" since your culture does not use `GregorianCalendar`.

[image]

In `UmAlQuraCalendar`, your DateTiem will be represented as 30-12-1437.

```
var dt = new DateTime(2016, 10, 1);  // Gregorian

var umAlQura = new UmAlQuraCalendar();

umAlQura.GetYear(dt);       // 1437
umAlQura.GetMonth(dt);      // 12
umAlQura.GetDayOfMonth(dt); // 30
```

https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/islam/ummalqura_converter.htm

That's why:

- `ddd` format specifier generates السبت ([(Yawm) as-Sabt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar) aka Saturday) since it is the abbreviated day name.
- `dd` format specifier generates `30` as expected.
- `MMM` format specifier generates ذو الحجة ([Dhu al-Hijjah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhu_al-Hijjah)) since it is the abbreviated month name.

As you can see, abbreviated day and month name switched in result. This is  probably a [Right to left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left) issue.

Comment: Actually i also have the same issue but didn't sort out i have converted my date to something like " 24/جمادى الثانية/1439 12:00 ص " Now i have to format it as dd/mm/yyyy . any clu ..?

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer . i have upvoted and sort out all things except i want to show year also which i cant :(